# How can I import excel file using nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to learn NextJs but I don't where should I put this variable. I know how to use it when using node/express but switching to nextjs, i'm having a difficult time

index.js

```
import fileupload from 'express-fileupload'
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
import fs from 'fs'


const uploadOpts = {
  useTempFiles: true,
  tempFileDir: '/tmp/'
}


app.post("/api/v1/books/import-excel",fileUpload(uploadOpts), async (req,res) => { 

...other code
}
```

How can I translate it to NextJs? I'm trying to learn the new `api routes`

api/uploadFile/route.ts

```
import fileupload from 'express-fileupload'
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
import fs from 'fs'


const uploadOpts = {
  useTempFiles: true,
  tempFileDir: '/tmp/'
}

export async function POST(){

}
```

I don't know how to properly add the `fileUpload` function